# Text substitution only in specific column of org table

Tags: org-mode, org-table, query-replace

I came across this problem today: I had a table with many entries and wanted to perform a text substitution (normal text substitution was sufficient as I hardly ever need regex text substitutions) in all cells of a single column. I ended up pressing `y` and `n` many times, instead of just `!` as it would've been had I had a way of restricting the text substitution (I used `M-%` / `query-replace`).

What's the best way of performing this task?

Comment: See `region-extract-function` which is respected by `query-replace`.  The tricky part is to get the buffer-positions of the table slice's rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the column as a rectangular region using `C-x SPC`
(`rectangle-mark-mode`) and then `M-%` (`query-replace`) will be
limited to that rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose the table with `org-table-transpose-table-at-point`, then select the relevant row (which used to be a column).

Narrow to region, replace-string, widen, and transpose again.

Note that you may lose hlines when transposing.